# Ajax is not defined on remote_form_for

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-2

I encountred an error on form submission. This form is defined as :

```
<% remote_form_for @my_object do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

The generated HTML is :

```
<form action="/my_objects" id="new_my_object" method="post"
   onsubmit="new Ajax.Request('/customers', {
      asynchronous:true,
      evalScripts:true,
      parameters:Form.serialize(this)
   }); return false;">
   ...
</form>
```

I encountred this JS error :

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Ajax is not defined
```

I read somewhere it's a Prototype error, but I don't understand the mistake I made.

My configuration is Rails 2.3.16, Ruby 1.8.6, jquery 1.9.1 and jquery-ui 1.10.2.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4999559/jquery-ui-and-prototype-conflict

Comment: You're using Prototype syntax but include only jQuery. Either switch to using Prototype or write the ajax call using jQuery methods.

Comment: @Juhana I'm not using Prototype syntax : Rails do it. How can I say to Rails 'use jQuery syntax' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default rails 2.x (and earlier versions), generate JS code for Prototype (cf [javascript_helper](http://apidock.com/rails/v2.3.8/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper) and [prototype_helper](http://apidock.com/rails/v2.3.8/ActionView/Helpers/PrototypeHelper).

To generate jQuery code in Rails 2.x, add [jrails](https://github.com/aaronchi/jrails) plugin for rails 2.x., and you will able to use the same rails helpers like remote_form_for or link_to_remote and jQuery.

This part of jrails.js may be obsolete with jquery 1.9 :

```
(function($) {
  $.ajaxSettings.accepts._default = "text/javascript, text/html, application/xml, text/xml, */*";
})(jQuery);
```

replace it by this code :

```js
$.ajaxPrefilter(function (options, originalOptions, jqXHR) { 
  options.beforeSend = function () {
    jqXHR.setRequestHeader("accept", '*/*;q=0.5, ' + $.ajaxSettings.accepts.script);
    if ($.isFunction(originalOptions.beforeSend)) originalOptions.beforeSend();
  };
});
```

to have ajax request detection working in a controller :

```ruby
def my_action
  respond_to |format|
    format.js { ... }
    format.html { ... }
  end
end
```

Comment: Good to see your huge improvement of the question! +1 for it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work with JQuery try this:

```
<%= form_for @my_object, :html => {:method => "post" }, :remote => true do |form| %>

<% end %>
```

Please also check the Rails Guidelines: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html

Answer (score 0):

I know this not an answer to your problem. But I use JQuery AJAX instead of Rails `remote attribute` to avoid these type of confusion. It is very handy to use AJAX with JQuery.

```
<% form_for @my_object do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>

<script>
  $(function(){
    $('#form_id').submit(function(){
      $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), function(data, status){
        alert(status)
      }) 
    })
  });
</script>
```